# How to take care of the percentage/rate of an absolute number as independent variable?

Tags: mixed-model, model

I am working on a mixed model, where suppose I have several stores of different sizes. The number of products manufactured in each store is different, say one store can manufacture 100 and other can do 10000 products as well. I have one independent variable as "total number of defects in a store". I am assuming that larger the products manufactured at a store, more will be the defects at that store.

Now if I take only the "absolute total number of defects" at a store, I am losing on the info about the total size of the stores. Can I use "percentage = (total defects at the store/total size of the store)" as my independent variable instead of "total defects at the store". Will that solve my issue? Or do I need to include interaction? Will the model become complicated in this scenerio?

Comment: Can you use size of the stores as an independent variable? This should help you avoid using percentages.

Comment: Also, you mentioned that number of defects is the independent variable. I would assume this would be your dependent variable instead?

Comment: Sorry for my extreme late reply! To your first answer, do you mean to use both the number of defects and size of store as independent variables?

Comment: Assuming that I want to use both of them at the independent variable side, what is the best possible way to do that? Is it to use percentages/rate (using one as numberator and other as denominator) or using both as two separate independent variable?

Comment: It is very unclear what your final objective is. Are you trying to predict number of errors? Calculating a percentage can be done even after predicting number of errors

Answer (score 1):

It is best to avoid using percentages as the dependent variable if at all possible, especially if you intend to use the denominator of the percentage as an independent variable. This will introduce sever bias due to mathematical coupling. Another pitfall is to use variables that are rates which are divided by the same denominator for a similar reason. A better approach in your case is to use the number of defects as the dependent variable and the size of the store as an independent variable.